# Printing the list of unique first name last name phone number email and address details in excel using Python

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x

We have created a python code to print "ABCD MNOP 282-567-4285 455 mindspace St., brisbane GA 35001 abcdmnop@gmail.com" which is nothing but First Name, Last Name, Mobile Number and Address

The code is as below

```
import random
first_names = ['ABCD', 'EFGH', 'IJKL', 'MNOP', 'QRST', 'UVWX', 'YZ']
last_names = ['ABCD', 'EFGH', 'IJKL', 'MNOP', 'QRST', 'UVWX', 'YZ']

street_names = ['indralok', 'mindspace', 'marine drive', 'kora kendra', 'bamdstand', 'mount mary', 
                'milan', 'paris','dubai', 'dindoshi', 'magathane', 'arnala']

cities_names = ['mumbai', 'banglore', 'pune', 'lucknow', 'patna', 'goa', 'ahmedabad', 'sydney', 
               'melbourne', 'brisbane','perth']

states = ['AL', 'AK', 'AZ', 'AR', 'CA', 'CO', 'CT', 'DC', 'DE', 'FL', 'GA', 'HI', 'ID', 'IL', 'IN', 'IA', 
          'KS', 'KY','LA', 'ME', 'MD', 'MA', 'MI', 'MN', 'MS', 'MO', 'MT', 'NE', 'NV', 'NH', 'NJ', 'NM', 
          'NY', 'NC', 'ND', 'OH','OK', 'OR', 'PA', 'RI', 'SC', 'SD', 'TN', 'TX', 'UT', 'VT', 'VA', 'WA', 
          'WV', 'WI', 'WY']

for num in range(100):

    first = random.choice(first_names)
    last = random.choice(last_names)

    phone = f'{random.randint(100, 999)}-567-{random.randint(1000, 9999)}'

    street_num = random.randint(100, 999)
    street = random.choice(street_names)
    city = random.choice(cities_names)
    state = random.choice(states)
    zip_code = random.randint(10000, 99999)
    address = f'{street_num} {street} St., {city} {state} {zip_code}'

    email = first.lower() + last.lower() + '@gmail.com'

    print (f'{first} {last} {phone} {address} {email}\n')
```

It outputs the result as

```
First Last Phone Number    Address                     Zip  Email Address

ABCD MNOP 282-567-4285 455 mindspace St., brisbane GA 35001 abcdmnop@gmail.com
```

in the console window

What we want to do is we have to print a range or random combination of first name last name address etc as output to excel file once we define the range

Expected output is like in an excel for the range we define:

```
MNOP MNOP 539-567-9221 106 paris St., goa LA 76016 mnopmnop@gmail.com

ABCD YZ 326-567-9757 173 magathane St., patna NV 52358 abcdyz@gmail.com

EFGH UVWX 507-567-6504 939 paris St., melbourne PA 45311 efghuvwx@gmail.com
```

If we define the range as 100 then we should get 100 different combination. We are not python experts just starting off any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Is it the writing to an excel sheet you need help with? In that case you can write to a .csv file: https://realpython.com/python-csv/

Comment: I mean it can write to anything Excel or CSV, the thing is it is not outputting the range of random values it just outputs only one and then stops.

What we are trying to achieve is we define a range and the code will create that many number of unique data in excel or CSV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following

```py
import random
import xlsxwriter

first_names = ['ABCD', 'EFGH', 'IJKL', 'MNOP', 'QRST', 'UVWX', 'YZ']
last_names = ['ABCD', 'EFGH', 'IJKL', 'MNOP', 'QRST', 'UVWX', 'YZ']
street_names = ['indralok', 'mindspace', 'marine drive', 'kora kendra', 'bamdstand', 'mount mary', 'milan', 'paris','dubai', 'dindoshi', 'magathane', 'arnala']
cities_names = ['mumbai', 'banglore', 'pune', 'lucknow', 'patna', 'goa', 'ahmedabad', 'sydney', 'melbourne', 'brisbane','perth']
states = ['AL', 'AK', 'AZ', 'AR', 'CA', 'CO', 'CT', 'DC', 'DE', 'FL', 'GA', 'HI', 'ID', 'IL', 'IN', 'IA', 'KS', 'KY','LA', 'ME', 'MD', 'MA', 'MI', 'MN', 'MS', 'MO', 'MT', 'NE', 'NV', 'NH', 'NJ', 'NM', 'NY', 'NC', 'ND', 'OH','OK', 'OR', 'PA', 'RI', 'SC', 'SD', 'TN', 'TX', 'UT', 'VT', 'VA', 'WA', 'WV', 'WI', 'WY']

N = 10

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('output.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

def get_random_value(input_list):
    return input_list[random.randint(0, len(input_list)-1)]

worksheet.write(0, 0, "First Name")
worksheet.write(0, 1, "Last Name")
worksheet.write(0, 2, "Street")
worksheet.write(0, 3, "City")
worksheet.write(0, 4, "State")

for i in range(1,N+1):    
    worksheet.write(i, 0, get_random_value(first_names))
    worksheet.write(i, 1, get_random_value(last_names))
    worksheet.write(i, 2, get_random_value(street_names))
    worksheet.write(i, 3, get_random_value(cities_names))
    worksheet.write(i, 4, get_random_value(states))

workbook.close()
```

Comment: This work like Magic. Kudos Abhilb. Thanks for Prompt Response!!

Answer (score 0):

You can store your data as a `pandas` dataframe and then write the dataframe to an excel file (`.csv`).

An example is as follows:

```py
import pandas as pd

data_list = []

for num in range(100):

    first = random.choice(first_names)
    last = random.choice(last_names)
    phone = f'{random.randint(100, 999)}-567-{random.randint(1000, 9999)}'
    street_num = random.randint(100, 999)
    street = random.choice(street_names)
    city = random.choice(cities_names)
    state = random.choice(states)
    zip_code = random.randint(10000, 99999)
    address = f'{street_num} {street} St., {city} {state} {zip_code}'
    email = first.lower() + last.lower() + '@gmail.com'

    data_list.append([first, last, phone, address, email])

data_df = pd.DataFrame(data_list)
data_df.columns = ['First', 'Last', 'Phone Number', 'Address', 'Email Address']
data_list.to_csv('data_excel.csv')
```

Comment: Thanks Jafet but I am not sure on how to implement this solution, if you can give me steps I can try this as well and let you know the results, the second solution given by Abhilb works great for me. I am quite new to Pyton and have no knowledge on pandas :(

Answer (score 0):

There are maybe better solutions, but you can check if your random combination is in a list of the random combinations you already created.